# Format text input onChange in order to get HH:MM:SS

Tags: javascript, time

I have an html input box type text. I'd like to, once the user start typing, it automatically format itself on change event in Javascript.

Something like...

(E.g.)

Start showing `00:00`, then when press 1, it shows `00:01`,

when I press 2, it shows `00:12`,

when I press 3, it shows `01:23`,

when I press 4, it shows `12:34`,

when I press 5, it shows `01:23:45`,

when I press 6, it shows `12:34:56`.

Max hours: 59

Max minutes: 59

Max seconds: 59

Comment: what should happen if user enters 999999? like if the entered details are out of order, what should be the default output?

Comment: Can you clarify what is the use case. What does user enters as input some random number or  time in seconds or milliseconds.

Comment: @light1 user should not be able to enter 999999, just number from 0 to 6. The default output should be 00:00. Hours should appear only if the digits are 5 or 6. First colon should appear if entered 3 digits (e.g. `123` should return `01:23`), second colon should appear if entered 5 digits (e.g. `12345` should return `01:23:45`).

Comment: @Mahi time in milliseconds should not be entered.

Comment: In your handler that handles new text being input, you just need to attempt to format the time and/or check the new characters that were entered. If the format works, then update the corresponding variables. If not, then set the textbox back to what it was before and no change will occur. This way you can prevent the user from typing in bad characters. If you could provide more context about what your handlers look like and how you are rendering the text box, that would be useful to get a good answer.